# Why `pprint()` in Sympy it didn't work on for loop?

Tags: python, sympy, pprint

This is my code

```
 14 def sum(output):
 15     result = 0
 16     for x, w in zip(output[0], output[1]):
 17         result+=w*np.exp(-((((b-a)/2.0)*x)+((a+b)/2.0))**2)
 18         pprint(w*exp(-((((b-a)/2.0)*x)+((a+b)/2.0))**2))
 19     return ((b-a)/2.0)*result
```

For this code if i call a function `sum` my output on terminal will print:

```
0.548543700179284
0.6
0.692267362730138
0.0
0.252818105473090
0.6
```

but if

```
 14 def sum(output):
 15     result = 0
 16     for x, w in zip(output[0], output[1]):
 17         result+=w*np.exp(-((((b-a)/2.0)*x)+((a+b)/2.0))**2)
 18     return ((b-a)/2.0)*result
 19
 20 pprint(w*np.exp(-((((b-a)/2.0)*x)+((a+b)/2.0))**2))
```

It will print a beautiful equation(I mean pprint() it's work!).

Why the first code can not print a beautiful equation like the second code?

Comment: Please add what `x` and `w` are defined to be in your second example.

Comment: @NilsWerner x and w it just elements of list.

Comment: and outside of `sum()`?

Comment: What I am saying: You are not showing all of the relevant code. Please add all parts that are necessary to have a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without more context, but probably because `w` and `x` are both defined both **inside and outside of your function `sum()`**.

Also note that the two lines are not the same:

```
pprint(w*exp(-((((b-a)/2.0)*x)+((a+b)/2.0))**2))
pprint(w*np.exp(-((((b-a)/2.0)*x)+((a+b)/2.0))**2))
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. What are `w` and `x` set to in the second example? The ones in line 16 are function local to `sum`.

Comment: I think the different forms are intentions. He is calculating a numerical answer in one and printing a symbolic answer in the other (assuming `exp` is `sympy.exp`).

Comment: But isnt the OP asking why the first code (wich is simply printing a number) doesnt print a formula like the second one?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice the OP used `np.exp` twice in the second one.